# Add unapproved suggested edits to the activity list

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, recent-activity

When you suggest an edit, nothing gets added to your activity page; this makes it a bit of a thing to remember that you made edits somewhere so you can check back and follow up if your edit is rejected or never reviewed.

The activity page records virtually every other action you take on a site, so it'd be nice to see suggestions there, too.